# Pipe string to hashtable to filtered value with single set of commands in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I've got a string that looks something like `$Str = "green=1,red=2,blue=3"` and I want to get the value for red.

I've got a two variable solution below, but was hoping there was a way I could just pipe the output of that to another command, but I keep running into "Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline" and I've had no luck figuring out if I can use a select or where somehow.

```
$final = $str -split ',' | convertfrom-stringdata
$final.'red'
```

Is there a way to run this all in one sequence of commands? Something like `$final = $str -split ',' | convertfrom-stringdata | $final.'red'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the usual method:

```
$final = ($str -split ',' | convertfrom-stringdata).'red'
```

Because of the way hashtables work in pipelines, you can also do below, but I would avoid it because it is going to be difficult in the future to tell what you intend to have happen here:

```
$final = $str -split ',' | convertfrom-stringdata | ForEach-Object { $_.'red' }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that, I figured it was something simple I was missing. By wrapping it in parenthesis, it basically turns it into a variable of it's own you can work with?